# Does the zero-value or sensitivity of an accelerometer changes over time?

Tags: accelerometer, gyroscope

Does the zero-value or sensitivity of an accelerometer changes over time? I.e is there something similar to the bias drift effect for gyroscopes, for accelerometers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. They also depend on temperature. And the temperature coefficient of offset (TCO) and the temperature coefficient of sensitivity (TCS) are different for the three axes. That's why you have the x,y,z calibration commands.